# WSProxy (or SOAP) to change CreatedDate of Folders

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, folder

I want to change the CreatedDate for Folders in SFMC.

Reasoning behind is that Audience Builder / Contact Builder is ordering the folder structure based of the CreatedDate unlike Email Studio which is using an alphabetic ordering.

I am using WSProxy but I am also happy to use SOAP.
Here is a sample of changing folder information in SFMC via Soap:
[Create, Retrieve, Update, and Delete Folders](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_retrieving_updating_and_deleting_folders.htm)

My WSProxy works to change the Name of the folder but it ignores the CreatedDate.

```
<script runat=server>
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

    api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    var res = api.updateItem("DataFolder", {
        ID: 12345,
        CreatedDate: new Date('2010-06-02T14:40:34Z'),
        Name: 'Rename The Folder'

    });
    Write(Stringify(res));
</script>
```

**Result:**

```
Status: "OK"
RequestID: "a5122813-2e9e-4ee1-bd2a-42c35cbcaae4"
Results: Array(1)
    0:
        Object: null
        UpdateResults: null
        ParentPropertyName: null
        StatusCode: "OK"
        StatusMessage: "Folder updated successfully."
        OrdinalID: 0
        ErrorCode: 0
        RequestID: null
        ConversationID: null
        OverallStatusCode: null
        RequestType: "Synchronous"
        ResultType: null
        ResultDetailXML: null
```

I have tried all sort of date formats

- string
- new Date()
- Iso format
- US format
- With timezone / offset
- Unix timestamp

It seems that I am not allowed to change the CreatedDate.
The updateItem is also successful if I only try to change the date itself.

My workaround would be

- to collect all folders
- save all DataExtension customerKeys from the folder
- create all folders again in the correct order
- relocate the DE's respectively
- delete the folders

However, at this stage this is a to big of a risk to mess up :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simple answer is....You can't.

CreatedDate is not a field you can edit. It is automatically added/filled in by the system when you create the folder. From there it is read-only.

Sample from Describe on DataFolder Object:

```xml
<Properties>
   <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
   <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
   <Name>CreatedDate</Name>
   <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
   <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
   <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
   <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
</Properties>
```

You will notice in the above, that `IsUpdatable` is `false`.

Now all this makes sense. Having the CreatedDate as editable would completely defeat the purpose of it. It is supposed to be a record of when the folder was actually created, not just a data field for you to manipulate.

I know that sucks for your use-case, but it really is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Gorton - makes sense. Only way to order is by re-creating I guess

Comment: As far as I know. I will try to check around and see if anyone knows of anything else, but not likely. If you absolutely NEED to re-order, the API I believe would be your best option as it can programatically move DEs from folder A to folder B. Removing the potential for human error and increasing speed of the process.